# OS X PHP — dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib

Tags: macos, command-line, php

What is the problem with my Mac's default PHP? Whenever I do `php -version`, it shows the following file missing information. How can I fix this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symlink libpq.5.3 to libpq.5:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libpq.5.3.dylib /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib
```

<sup>Make a backup first.</sup>